# Setting bool value in azure function trigger via app settings

Tags: azure, azure-functions, cosmosdbtrigger

is there any way I can set value of bool param StartFromBeginning  from appsetting ? %StartFromBeginning% works for string not for bool

```
[FunctionName(nameof(MyAzureFunction))]
public async Task RunAsync([CosmosDBTrigger(
    databaseName: "myCosmosDbName",
    collectionName: "myCollectionName",
    ConnectionStringSetting = "cosmosConnectionString",
    LeaseCollectionName = "leases",
    CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists = true,
    MaxItemsPerInvocation = 1000,
    StartFromBeginning = true)]IReadOnlyList<Document> documents)
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far I know, it is not possible to pass the values as Boolean to the Parameters in function definition by fetching from `local.settings.json` because `StartFromBeginning` property in the `CosmosDBTrigger` attribute supports only constant values.

The values must be directly passed in the function definition for Boolean variables.

I have declared `StartFromBeginning` value in `local.settings.json`:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "demo": "AccountEndpoint=<cosmos_Conn_String>;",
    "StartFromBeginning": true
  }
}
```

- I tried passing the "StartFromBeginning" variable as parameter in the function definition, but it is not allowed and leading to the error Cannot implicitly *convert type string to bool* . Because the value is being passed in the quotes`""`(as a string) to the Boolean variable.

[image]

Hence, it is recommended to use as shown below:

```cs
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static void Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
    databaseName: "<database>",
    containerName: "<container>",
    Connection = "demo",
    LeaseContainerName = "leases",
    CreateLeaseContainerIfNotExists = true,
    StartFromBeginning =true)]IReadOnlyList<ToDoItem> input,

    ILogger log)
{
    if (input != null && input.Count > 0)
    {
        log.LogInformation("Documents modified " + input.Count);
        log.LogInformation("First document Id " + input[0].id);
    }
}
```

```
Functions:

        Function1: cosmosDBTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-01-10T09:45:49.361Z] Executing 'Function1' (Reason='New changes on container kpccontainer at 2024-01-10T09:45:49.3151264Z', Id=afb8df08-82ff-4XXXXX7-40d73691d860)
[2024-01-10T09:45:49.384Z] Documents modified 1
[2024-01-10T09:45:49.387Z] First document Id b671723b-3132XXXXXX6fb496dcd4
[2024-01-10T09:45:49.415Z] Executed 'Function1' (Succeeded, Id=afb8df08-82XXXXX7-40d7XXX860, Duration=86ms)
[2024-01-10T09:45:51.115Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000FXXXX31CC'.
```